# Using glm to predict continuous variables between 0 and 1 family=binomial(link='logit') gives error

Tags: r, logistic-regression, glm

I'm trying to use glm to estimate a logistic regression on a continuous variable between 0 and 1 using the following code, but am getting the attached error:

```
> glm(y ~ x, data=test_data, family=binomial(link = 'logit'))
Error in eval(family$initialize) : y values must be 0 <= y <= 1
```

However, when I do a summary on test_data, the df has y values that are entirely between 0 and 1...

```
> summary(test_data)
       y                  x         
 Min.   :0.000000   Min.   :0.0000  
 1st Qu.:0.001510   1st Qu.:0.0000  
 Median :0.003664   Median :1.0000  
 Mean   :0.025847   Mean   :0.5386  
 3rd Qu.:0.009054   3rd Qu.:1.0000  
 Max.   :1.000000   Max.   :1.0000
```

Can anyone help me understand what the issue here is? If I check the type of the variables, they are both numeric:

```
> class(test_data$y)
[1] "numeric"
> class(test_data$x)
[1] "numeric"
```

Comment: Check your variables using `class(variable)`. If they are character, you need to convert them.

Comment: When I check the class of both variables, they are numeric. Updated the post above to reflect this.

Comment: Add a (small) sample of your data.

Comment: Shouldn't your y be a factor? (e.g. 0 and 1)

Comment: @Matt factor here only meaningful if the dependent variable is a categorical variable, eg, male/female for which there's no intrinsic numeric value and the factor will assign these.  Numeric input is quite fine on its own, such as a percentage value of some measurement.

Comment: @Matt it shouldn't need to be - as I mentioned in the title above, I am using the logit to predict a continuous variable between zero and 1. This is relatively common in economics. For instance, see this paper: https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/135048596356636

Comment: Try: glm(as.numeric(test_data$y) ~ as.numeric(test_data$x), family=binomial(link='logit'))

Comment: @araspion It's possible to fit that model but you would either need the 'sample size' that went into the denominator for each value of y. If you don't have sample sizes that could be an issue.  If there aren't any sizes to begin with (because y isn't actually a proportion) then you would need to fit a different model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suggest you try:

```
which(as.numeric(test_data$x) < 0 | as.numeric(test_data$x) > 1)
which(as.numeric(test_data$y) < 0 | as.numeric(test_data$y) > 1)
```

Comment: Is the check on test_data$x required?

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue here - after drilling down into the data, there are a small number of rows with very small, negative values of y (likely due to rounding errors), e.g.,:

```
> test_data[276,]
# A tibble: 1 x 2
          y     x
      <dbl> <dbl>
1 -1.47e-17     0
```

However, these out-of-range values do not show up in summary.